# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk creates server instance when create new environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am a beginner in Amazon. Recently I have uploaded my four different web applications and web services on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk service.

My problem is: when I publish my web app using AWS .NET toolkit on Elastic Beanstalk, it creates a new environment for each application and creates a new EC2 instance for each environment.

Can anybody please tell, is this EC2 instance of Amazon Windows Server instance?
Can't we deploy more than one web app in same Environment and same EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

we use the Java SDK, and the behaviour is the same. I think is the natural way in AWS EB: One app => One server. I think the main reason is that AWS EB  is a full stack of a Load Balancer, alarms, etc, and specially auto scaling policies. Since EB offers a fully managed Auto Scaling features, it does not have sense to add more servers to your stack based on a server with more than one application: Imagine that you have an application that consumes the 80% of the CPU / Inbound trafic / memory...), while the other consumes the 10%. Both are running on the same server... why you would scale the second one if it has enougth space to grow whith just one instance?